# Is there a RF signal device for a 120 or 240 vac wire to start and stop a standby generator?

Tags: rf, generator, electrical

Our standby generators automatically start when a switch in the automatic transfer switch closes and the gen stops when that switch opens. Usually we bury 2 16ga wires along with two 120/240v hot and ground wires from the ATS to the generator that are used only when the generator runs during a power outage.  But often the 120/240v and ground wire are already buried for a previous non-automatic tractor PTO generator.  So now we need to trench and bury another two 16ga wires often several hundred feet in length.
   Is there or could a 12 vdc transmitter device be designed that could send a radio signal down any of the three #4 to #000ga generator supply wires that would trigger a receiver and switch to start the generator and when the main line power was restored would open the same switch to stop the generator when the ATS micro switch opens?

Comment: Power Line Telecommunications (PLT) for SCADA is a common method. But I do not have any product recommendations.

Comment: Schneider may have some solution. https://www.se.com/ww/en/product-category/4100-power-monitoring-and-control/

Comment: There is power line carrier equipment that may be more suitable if all that is needed to be transmitted is something like a single contact closure or a few pieces of discrete information.

Comment: I don't know of any product to help you. But this is a good example of why everyone should bury 2 inch conduit (at least) when they run their PTO generator wires in the first place so all they have to do is pull two new wires for the ATS.

Comment: Should this question be migrated to DIY stack exchange? Electrician type questions are often migrated there. https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mkeith - Questions involving buried conduit and power are common at DIY, but I don't think that particular SE would have any idea how to answer the original question of how to send data over the same power lines he has buried.

Answer (score 0):

Transmitters can be capacitively coupled to a power transmission line, but this may not even be necessary in your case.  In the short distances you are stating, a completely wireless solution should suffice, given there is a power source at the remote generator.

However, it seems to me in my initial thoughts, that a load sensing circuit could be installed at the generator end that, along with a relay, could serve your purposes without having to install some over-complicated wireless system.  That, however, would require a separate question, like "How can I engage a remote generator using only the supply wires that are currently installed"...